# How to due with the cross domain in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, request

My environment is Nodejs, and I want to make request(http) to api in the internet.

But there are some problems, after using webpack, the console would show me cross

domain error. I guess it is because my api and webpack-server have diffrent in

port. What should I do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is caused by the server not properly sending a CORS header to allow the request.

If the API is one of your own, you can enable CORS on your server for one, many, or all domains that attempt to access the API. How to do this depends on your server configuration.

If the API is provided by someone else, you may need to contact them or consult their documentation on how to perform a CORS request to their services.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the problem of CORS. Sadly, the API is provided by someone else. I think whether it is ok if I use Php file to request, which pass html file the result, and I would not pack Php file with Webpack.

By the way, thanks again.